# Launching Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco

I am trying to install packet tracer. I installed java and than packet tracer, but when I'm launching it from terminal, I see the output as "Starting packet tracer 7.1.1" and nothing happens. When I'm searching it, I cant see packet tracer installed!